# Xcode File not found error during parse XLSX

Tags: ios, swift

I am parsing XLXS file. when I execute code getting error

> "Fatal error: XLSX file corrupted or does not exist".

I double checked test.xlsx file available inside project.what is wrong with the code. Any help will be appreicated

```
guard let file = XLSXFile(filepath: "./test.xlsx") else {
            fatalError("XLSX file corrupted or does not exist")
        }

        do{

            for path in try file.parseWorksheetPaths() {
                let ws = try file.parseWorksheet(at: path)
                for row in ws.data?.rows ?? [] {
                    for c in row.cells {
                        print(c)
                    }
                }
            }
        }catch{
            print("error", error)
        }
```

Comment: What is "./" at the beginning of the filename supposed to mean? Have you tried without that prefix? Have you tried with an absolute file path?

Comment: you meant this path  let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource:"test", ofType:"xlsx") ??

Answer (score 1):

filepath can't accessing from bundle directory, need to pass correct path:

```
guard let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "test", ofType: "xlsx", inDirectory: nil) else {
    fatalError("XLSX file not exist")
}
guard  let file = XLSXFile(filepath: filePath) else {
    fatalError("XLSX file corrupted")
}
```

One more thing to need to check, while adding `XLSX` file to project it must added to target & copy to bundle directory:

[image]

Comment: And if you're a dork like me and it says "Cannot Find 'Bundle' in Scope" don't forget to Import Foundation at the top of your Swift file.

Answer (score 0):

You should get the filePath using the following :

```
  if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "test", ofType: "xlsx") {
           //Use your file here
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try replacing

```
guard let file = XLSXFile(filepath: "./test.xlsx") else {
```

with

```
guard var file = XLSXFile(filepath: "./test.xlsx") else {
```

I do not have experience dealing with files but I hope this helps you

Comment: your answer did not fix the issue